# Postgis installation on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I am trying to install postgis on ubuntu Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

I search the repo and find a package called `postgresql-9.1-postgis`. I then installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

It also installed the following dependencies:

```
libgeos-3.2.2 libgeos-c1 libproj0 postgis proj-data
```

I then thought I could easily do (inside my schema):

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

But I instead got the wonderful error detailed below:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory


********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

Any idea how I can finalize the installation so that I can use the damn extension?

Ta

Comment: Your question relates to problems installing and/or using software. This Q&A site expects questions relating to problems writing software. Try [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) instead.

Comment: Can I ask the same the question there?

Comment: Sure you can. Your current SO account is valid there as well.

Comment: Check this out https://www.phparticles.com/database/postgis-installation-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver/

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you installed postgis version 1.5.x. You have to install postgis 2.0. Before install add correct repository. [This](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/index.html#ubuntu-debian) link will help you to add correct repository.